# Rails 4 console with spring locked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spring-gem

I'm using Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1.0.rc1. When excute `rails c`, it's locked.

Using `Ctrl-C` to stop, I got error logs belore:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:47:in `gets': Interrupt
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:47:in `verify_server_version'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:19:in `call'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:23:in `call'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from ~/Sites/ihaveu/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

After spring removed, `rails c` resumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by updating Rails 4.1.0.rc1 to 4.1.0.rc2

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue today on Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.0.3, and I managed to fix it by stopping `spring` before trying again:

```
$ spring stop
Spring stopped.
$ bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.3)
[1] pry(main)>
```